# when running elastic search sink connector, getting warn Encountered an illegal document error -> Response status: 'BAD_REQUEST'

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to capture confluent audit log to elasticsearch using elasticsearch sink connector
In my case,
I created a docker- compose file for kafka connect and then appending elastic sink connector config on top of that and after that log message is sinking to elasticsearch cluster.
But while running the whole process,in kafka connect log I am getting some warning,

```
[2023-03-17 15:47:28,630] WARN [elastic-sink|task-0] Encountered an illegal document error -> Response status: 'BAD_REQUEST',
```

2023-03-17 21:17:28 Index: 'confluent-audit-log-events',
2023-03-17 21:17:28  Document Id: 'confluent-audit-log-events+1+36008'.
2023-03-17 21:17:28 Ignoring and will not index record. (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient:649)

I do not know why it is coming, is there any configuration, I am missing in elasticsearch sink connector config and is this impacts the sinking of data in elastic search

Can anyone please help me with this?

For your reference, I am attaching the docker-compose and elastic search config

docker-compose for connector

```
---
version: '3.5'
services:
  connect:
    container_name: kafka-connect
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.2.4
    container_name: kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "5005:5005"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "bootstrap"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "connect-7.3.1"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-configs-7.3.1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-offsets-7.3.1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-status-7.3.1
      CONNECT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"  
      #CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "url"
      #CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE: "USER_INFO"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO: "username:secret"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /data
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.reflections=ERROR
      #CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.3.1.jar
      CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY: All
      # Connect worker
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='user' password='password';"
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      CONNECT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "HTTPS"
      # Connect consumer
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='user' password='password';"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE: "true"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
```

elasticsearch sink connector config file

```
curl -X PUT \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{
               "tasks.max": "1",
               "connector.class": "ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
               "topics": "confluent-audit-log-events",
               "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
               "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
               "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
               "consumer.override.bootstrap.servers": "bootstrap",
               "consumer.override.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
               "consumer.override.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
               "consumer.override.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"\" password=\"\";",
               "consumer.override.client.dns.lookup": "use_all_dns_ips",
               "schema.ignore": "true", 
               "key.ignore": "true",
               "connection.url": "elasticsearch url",
               "connection.username": "user",
               "connection.password": "password",
               "errors.log.enable": true,
               "errors.log.include.messages": true,
               "write.method": "UPSERT",
               "max.retries": "1",  
               "retry.backoff.ms": "1000",
               "batch.size": "100", 
               "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "WARN",
               "behavior.on.null.values": "IGNORE",
               "linger.ms": "10000"
          }' \
     http://localhost:8083/connectors/elastic-sink/config | jq .
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check the mapping configuration on elasticsearch. If possible, please send me the index-template on elasticsearch

Comment: Why *send*? As in *so your question can be answered*? Then it should be edited into the question!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).